# Converting Image to BASE64 String in swift

Tags: ios, swift2, uiimage, base64, nsdata

I am trying to convert the Image which is picked by user either from his Photos or Take New from Camera.  I am able to convert the image into base64 string but the problem is that it takes too much time and prints a long infinite string

Here is the output of String which i am getting

[image]

here is my code:

```
// Image picker from Gallery
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
        imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        profileImage.image = image

    }

    // Image Picker from Camera

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        profileImage.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

        addPicBtn.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)

        let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profileImage.image!)!
        let imageStr = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        print(imageStr)


    }
```

Comment: Since it is converting it is taking the time, it should not effect while uploading the image with base64 text.

Comment: what you want to do now ??  i mean where are you facing problem ...??

you can check Base64 string  from below link , if it is  encoded right or not 

http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Comment: @dhiru its taking a lot of time while converting it into an string

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually it will not take time to convert but for printing, it will take more time so don't print it...

Comment: i want this string to be added in database

Comment: you add directly. It won't take much time.

Comment: but when i suppose to pick image from gallery, application holds there for a few mins

Comment: If you want less quality image than use UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagePicked, 0.5)!
than string value will come less, for loading use dispatch_async method and show loading spinner till image not come...

Comment: can you tell me how to decode the string into image

Comment: let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: strBase64, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!
let decodedimage:UIImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)!
print(decodedimage)
yourImageView.image = decodedimage

Comment: it shows me nil at **let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: strBase64, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!**

Comment: Try this let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: strBase64, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129907/discussion-between-jayesh-gyanchandani-and-sagar-snehi).

Answer (score 9):

**You can apply this code**

```
let imageData: Data? = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(getImage(), 0.4)
let imageStr = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters) ?? ""
print(strBase64)
```

Comment: this will reduce the quality of images

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 version. This simple func worked well for me. Confirmed decoded image back using this: https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter
Hope this helps someone.

```
public static func  convertImageToBase64String(image : UIImage ) -> String 
{
    let strBase64 =  image.pngData()?.base64EncodedString()
    return strBase64!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image extension first.

// .png

```
    guard let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage) else {
        return ""
    }
```

// .JPEG

```
   guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage, 1) else {
                return ""
    }
```

// BASE 64

```
  imageData.base64EncodedString()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let imageData: Data? = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(YourImage, 0.4)
let imageStr = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters) ?? ""
print(imageStr,"imageString")
```

[image: After printing imageStr you will huge output like in this attached image below, it means you are done successfully.]

Comment: this output means that we have successfully converted image into string