# Data is not converted into String

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to convert an image into data and then that data into a string using this code but it fail on conversion when i want to convert data into string

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImageImageView.image!)
let datastring = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
```

it gives some in data, but always nil in datastring
cant figure it out where the problem is if anyone knows please help... thanks

Comment: What is your expected result? An image cannot normally be represented as string, as the data is binary.

Comment: are you trying to base64 encode the image? see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989079/converting-image-to-base64-string-in-swift. otherwise like PMF said, image data can't normally be converted to a utf8 string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if let img = selectedImageImageView.image {
    if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) {
        if let datastring = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength) {
            println(datastring)
        }
    }
}
```